# Executable (and syncable) build output without packaging

Tags: java, jar, build, gradle

I have multi-project setup in Gradle (mostly Java) with lots of internal and external dependencies. One of those projects produces jar with Main class, that I want to execute outside the build for special kind of tests (it is not meant to be deployed in production). I don't need to upload it anywhere, it is enough if I get what I need on the same machine that build runs.

I could just make the task that creates uber-jar with this project's classes and all its dependencies, to get self-executable jar for those tests. The problem with this approach is that it takes 10-15 minutes to create such a jar and I don't want to do it every time i change single line of code somewhere.

Is there some kind of distribution/assembly task, that, after everything is built, copy resultant jars and dependency jars to some folder that I specify? And, when I run build again, it will copy ONLY those jars, that have actually changed since the last build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, looks like I achieved what I wanted by simply using installApp task from [Application plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html):

```
apply plugin:'application'

mainClassName = 'org.openjdk.jmh.Main'

installApp {
    into 'D:\\Some\\directory'
}
```

It doesn't do syncing for every jar, but just checks whole directory. However since it does no packaging, but just copies only the jars I need from one place to another it's very fast. Wicked!

I only wish this plugin and its task were more documented in case I want to customize it a bit.